# React Redux REST API - when to reload data into application

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-redux, mern

I am currently working on a MERN stack application with a React Redux front end. It is an job management system with a calendar showing booked in jobs/events.

I have a question regarding best practices around making API calls and loading data into my app. The database is small scale at the moment so a small amount of data is loaded into my Redux store.

When is best to make GET requests to load my data into my app and handle changes made by other clients? Do I load all data on each page load? Is there a cleaner/more efficient way to do this?

Any help/guidance is much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my personal experience, I believe that if your application will be accessed by different users simultaneously, you could GET the calendar data when a user first accesses his calendar and whenever the user is going to add a new job/event. This way he has access to the latest data before creating a new event. Also when creating an event, if the API returns an error because there is a collision between events you can update the data on the FE. This would be a lazy approach and it wouldn't keep the calendar constantly updated.
If you need data to be fresh you could also set a timer and execute GETs periodically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Tomas, this is what I was looking for. Much appreciated